# Ajax.BeginForm(new AjaxOptions {}) Exceptions

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, exception

Two options stick out. OnSuccess and OnFailure. These allow me to call functions if the page update succeeds or fails. So, I have an Action that is called that sends and email and has this code...

```
try
            {
                // Code to send email
                return Content("Your message has been successfully!", "text/html");
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return Content("An error occurred sending your message...", "text/html");
            }
```

Problem is that even if it falls into the Exception it still calls OnSuccess. What I want to do is call another function when it falls into the Exception. How would I go about doing this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The OnFailure callback will be called when the HTTP status code returned by the server is not 200. In your example in both case it is 200. You have cought the exception and swallowed it.

So:

```
catch (Exception ex)
{                
    Response.StatusCode = 500;
    return Content("An error occurred sending your message...", "text/html");
}
```

and then:

```
function onFail(result) {
    alert(result.responseText);
};
```

Comment: Seems that now when it fails when I give it status 500, it doesn't execute UpdateTargetId in my AjaxOptions and I have to do it manually. Does this only fire on success?

Answer (score 0):

Basically your not setting the status of the response or the error message back to the client. Also I gather your recieving JSON its probably a good idea to return JSON. 
Also be aware IIS can swallow the exceptions so as in below example as @Rob Stevenson-Leggett shows:

```
Response.TrySkipIisCustomErrors = true
```

Here is an example on stackoverflow from a previous question:
[How to return correct response on error in ASP.NET MVC 3.0 via JSON?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6456265/how-to-return-correct-response-on-error-in-asp-net-mvc-3-0-via-json)

hopefully this helps.